# How to create an empty anonymous table in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

In Postgres if I want to create an "anonymous table" (i.e. a temporary query based on data not in the database) I can use `VALUES`, for example:

```
select * from (values (1, 'Hello world'), (100, 'Another row')) as foo (mycol1, mycol2);
```

But how can I create an anonymous table with no rows?  (This is for a code generator, so the question isn't quite as odd as it sounds!).  The following does not work

```
select * from (values  ) as foo (mycol1, mycol2);
```

because I get

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ")"
LINE 1: select * from (values  ) as foo (mycol1, mycol2);
                               ^
```

I know a work around

```
select * from (values (NULL, NULL)) as foo (mycol1, mycol2) where mycol1 is not NULL;
```

but is there a better or "more official" way?

(I would also be interested to know if it is possible to create a table with no columns!)

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking...

Comment: What do you want to do with "anonymous table"? The ability to create such table looks like a bug.

Comment: @Denis, what I'm asking is whether there's a nicer way to do: `select * from (values (NULL, NULL)) as foo (mycol1, mycol2) where mycol1 is not NULL`.

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko, by anonymous table I mean a temporary query based on data not in the database, such as the one returned from my first select statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can do something like this:

```
select null::text as a, null::int as b
limit 0
```

Comment: I like it!  My preferred answer so far.  Syntactically very clean.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    generate_series(0, -1)
```

Comment: That certainly gives me a query returning zero rows!  But can I make it have an arbitary number of columns with arbitrary types?

Comment: @TomEllis Use `SELECT null::number, null::varchar ... FROM generate_series(0, -1)`

Comment: Ah yes, that works.  And to get column names I can do `SELECT null::int as foo, null::varchar as bar FROM generate_series(0, -1)`